# Android jetpack navigation custom back button overlapping back arrow on back

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-navigation, android-jetpack

Using **android jetpack navigation** in combination with toolbar and drawer is that the root destination has a hamburger menu icon (to toggle the drawer) and in child fragments there is a back button.

Also an animation exists when opening / closing child fragments on the back arrow.

Now the problem: In one of my child fragments I set a custom navigation back button

```
toolbar_main.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_clear)
```

This also works, but upon closing there is a "glitch" where

1. The custom icon disappears
2. **The back arrow is visible for a short while** (this is the "glitch"
3. The child closes and the root fragment (with burger icon) is visible again

Question:

Is this "glitch" a bug or do I have to call something other than **setNavigationIcon** (like ActionBarDrawerToggle or similar) ?

Comment: Navigation doesn't support custom navigation icons as per [this still open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121078028), so yeah, your custom icon is going to conflict if you're using any of the `NavigationUI` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **in each Fragment**

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    val activity = context as BaseActivity
    if (navController.backStack.size > 3) {
        activity.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getNavigationIcon())
    }
}
```

more than 3 because:

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/startFragment"> <----- always +1

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startFragment"> <----- startFragment + 1 = 2

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"> <----- startFragment + 1 = 3

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"> <----- startFragment + 1 = 3

</navigation>
```